# Apple subscription callback doesn't notify us when subscription expires (Sandbox)

Tags: ios, sandbox, in-app-subscription, auto-renewable

We have a problem with Apple subscription callback on Sandbox environment. When I purchase an auto-renewable subscription on Sandbox env, apple sends first callback only after 1-2 min. It's ok. But when the first expiration period ends apple not always notify us about extending a subscription. But we should receive notification_type = RENEWAL always at the end of the expiration period. Sometimes we receive notifications sometimes we don't. Do you know how can we check where is the problem? Maybe Apple has some troubles because we couldn't find any problems on our side.

[image: example]

Comment: Sandbox purchases renew 6 times in sandbox then stop.

Comment: @enc_life Yes. We know it. But shouldn't sandbox env send us apple subscription callback with a new expiration date for subscriptions?

Answer (score 1):

`RENEWAL` events are sent when a subscription has expired, then later, the user starts the subscription again.

See: [Apple Subscription Notifications are Almost Useless](https://www.revenuecat.com/2018/09/24/apple-subscription-notifications-are-almost-useless)